# QML indeterminate ProgressBar doesn't animated on Desktop Qt 6.1.2 MSVC2019 64bit Windows 10

Tags: qt, qml

It seems that `QML` indeterminate `ProgressBar` doesn't animated on **Desktop Qt 6.1.2 MSVC2019 64bit Windows 10**. The code is showed as followed:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ProgressBar {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        indeterminate: true
    }
}
```

The result is showed as followed:

[image]

And it works fine on **Desktop Qt 5.15.2 MSVC2019 64bit Windows 10**. The result is showed as followed:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QT6.1 - Qml Why does the ProgressBar not have an animation corresponding to the indeterminate property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68304728/qt6-1-qml-why-does-the-progressbar-not-have-an-animation-corresponding-to-the)

Comment: you should use [style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html#using-styles-in-qt-quick-controls)

Comment: Does it mean that it's a bug for Qt-6.1.2, as it works fine for Qt-5.15.2? @Parisa.H.R

Comment: yes , exactly use style .